# Python/Django datetime comparison

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm confused on datetime comparison with Django datetime field, here is the code

```
now = datetime.now()
delta = talk.when + timedelta(minutes=(talk.duration + 10))
if now > delta:
    return True
return False
```

`talk` is just datetime field,
`duration` is integer field

`now` - should have hours equal to `17:43` however I've `5:43` (`datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 14, 5, 43, 24, 228401)`)

What is the problem, whats wrong in the code?

**Now it works**

I just added USER_ENV_TZ variable with my local timezone and used `utcnow`

```
if os.getenv('ENV_USER_TZ', None):
    TIME_ZONE = os.getenv('ENV_USER_TZ') # changed to UTC
```

Thanks,
Sultan

Comment: Could you please provide some details about what version of Django you're using and what settings you have enabled in your settings.py?

Comment: Is duration in minutes? Or seconds? Also, what timezone are you operating in? It's best to use `datetime.utcnow()` and convert everything to utc when it enters your system to avoid timezone woes.

Comment: @BluePeppers / sultan - Would one of y'all remake your comment as an answer, so it can be voted up / accepted?

Comment: Could you answer your own question so that you can accept it and others can vote on it?

Comment: Yes @NoctisSkytower I'll do it but for now I've notification `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Now it works**

I just added USER_ENV_TZ variable with my local timezone and used `utcnow` suggested by @ BluePeppers

```
if os.getenv('ENV_USER_TZ', None):
    TIME_ZONE = os.getenv('ENV_USER_TZ') # changed to UTC
```

Thank you all